# Bash - Iterating over select menu options after choosing an option?

Tags: bash

I am reading up on Select menus in Bash:

[Making menus with the select built-in](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html)

I am quite confused when it comes to iterating over the options in the menu and would appreciate any feedback on this.

Using the code here as a starting point:

[How can I create a select menu in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1716/243213)

We get the following output:

```
root@dev:~/# ./test.sh
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Quit
Please enter your choice: 1
you chose choice 1
Please enter your choice: 2
you chose choice 2
Please enter your choice: 4
root@dev:~/#
```

What I would like to try to do, is show the select options again once an option has been chosen, so the output would be like:

```
root@dev:~/# ./example.sh
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Quit
Please enter your choice: 1
you chose choice 1
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Quit
Please enter your choice: 2
you chose choice 2
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Quit
Please enter your choice: 3
root@dev:~/#
```

So I have given this a Bash (L) and and tried to loop through the options (array?):

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
  case $opt in
    "Option 1")
      echo "you chose choice 1"
      # Create an incrementing value
      loop=1;
      # Loop through each option
      for option in ${options[@]} ; do
        # Echo the option
        echo "$loop) $option";
        # Increment the loop
        loop=$((loop+1));
      done
      ;;
    "Quit")
      break
      ;;
    *) echo invalid option;;
  esac
done
```

But then I get an output like:

```
root@dev:~/# ./stumped.sh
1) Option 1
2) Quit
Please enter your choice: 1
you chose choice 1
1) Option
2) 1
3) Quit
Please enter your choice:
```

So it seems that the array values are separated by spaces here?

To my understanding: `options=("Option 1" "Quit")` is creating an array of 2 values and not of 3 however it is being interpreted in Bash as 3 and I am not sure why.

Could someone enlighten me and explain why this is happening?

Comment: You should create a `function` that brings up the menu, and then a `while` loop using the `function` inside. As it stands, your code never loops (it has no repetition construct, such as `for`, `while`, etc)

Comment: You didn't quote `${options[@]}` in the inner loop.

Comment: @slezica Updated the final code block in my question, was a typo there. It does loop just not as I might expect?

Comment: @choroba each of the options becomes $option, I referenced this in the inner loop?

Comment: The code is a little convoluted. The loop should be on the outside (after all, you're repeating the operation). I suggested a possible writing below

Comment: `for option in ${options[@]} ` is interpreted as for option in "Option" "1" "Quit".

Comment: @slezica It is hardly convoluted as it's a select menu with a for loop inside of it. I'll accept your constructive criticism though I am literally just playing with Bash here. The problem here, is that I have found something that I do not really understand but would like to: Why a for loop over `options=("Option 1" "Quit")` produces 3 results instead of my expected 2. Will check out the answer though, thanks.

Comment: @WalterA Thanks, that's my issue exactly and if that is the case how would one loop over this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create a `function` that shows the menu and echoes the user's choice:

```
function show_menu {
  select option in "${OPTIONS[@]}"; do
    echo $option
    break
  done
}
```

Now, we can wrap that `function` in a loop, and only break out if the user picked `Quit`:

```
while true; do
  option=$(show_menu)

  if [[ $option == "Quit" ]]; then
    break
  fi
done
```

Voila!

Comment: It might take me a long time to comprehend what you have done here but thanks. This being said, it's not the answer to my question even though it is likely a better solution.

Comment: I'll admit this does work well... Thanks for the interesting example :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want the numbered options shown each iteration, let select do that for you.

```
options=("Option one" "two"  three "and number four"  quit)
while true; do
   select item in "${options[@]}" ; do
      if [ -n "${item}" ]; then
         break
      fi
      echo "Sorry, please enter a number as shown."
      break
   done;
   if [[ "${item}" = "quit" ]]; then
     break
   fi
   if [ -n "${item}" ]; then
      echo "Your answer is ${item}"
   fi
done
```